# German A1 Grammar

Tags: accusative

Can someone explain the difference in these two sentences?

Sentence 1: das Kind sieht einen Hund.

Sentence 2: der Hund sieht ein Kind.

If both the kid and the dog are doing the same thing (seeing), why does it change from "einen" when the kid sees, to "ein" when the dog sees?

Comment: Table to go with the answer: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hund** is masculine in declension. **Kind** is neuter. The masculine form of the indefinite article is **einen** in the accusative. The neuter form is **ein**.